# Is there a way to speedup keyboard popup?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, keyboard, external-keyboard

I used a lot of keyboards but all of them are very slow (not typing, just popup time). Is there a way to minimize that time or I should to buy phone with hardware keyboard? :-]

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by popup (time)? Is it the little boxes which popups when you press a letter (and the box shows the letter that was pressed)? Or are you saying that you type fast but the letters don't show up as fast in the textbox / textarea (not talking about the popup I mentioned earlier)?

Comment: @geffchang I think he means the open and close animation of the keyboard itself when a text field is activated.

Comment: As @onik said popup time is time between user press text field and keyboard appear on screen. I used a lot of phones, such as Sony Xperia X8 / Samsung Galaxy SII / Cubot GT72

Comment: Have you tried enabling Developer options (in Settings, click About Device several times), and disabling stuffs like: (1) Window animation scale, (2) Transition animation scale, (3) Animator duration scale. I'm not sure if it'll help, but it's worth a try.

Comment: And what phone are you using by the way? Some lower-end phones are really slow. Not much you can do about that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @geffchang said, disabling animations in Developer options is right way